# Why does LaTeX tell me that a { is missing?

Tags: errors, itemize

Whenever I compile my document including the following code, it produces satisfactory output on the pdf, but gives me an error:

```
43
Missing { inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \gdef 
l.43 \item $\mu_\hat{p}
                       $ = mean of all possible values of $\hat{p} = \pi$. \\
```

---

```
\begin{itemize}
\item $\mu_\hat{p}$ = mean of all possible values of $\hat{p} = \pi$. \\
\item $\sigma_\hat{p}$ = standard deviation of all possible values of \^p =     $\sqrt{\frac{\pi(1-\pi)}{n}}$ \\
\item CLT (for \^p): If $n\pi \geq 10$ \underline{AND} $n(1-\pi) \geq to$, then the histogram of all possible values of \^p will be approximately normal. \\
\end{itemize}
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Why are you mixing `\^p` with `\hat{p}`? It's the same symbol and it should be in the same shape every time.

Comment: You need braces for the subscripts: `\mu_{\hat{p}}` and `\sigma_{\hat{p}}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: Thanks! These are merely notes for a stats class that I typed in LaTeX as a way to try to learn the language, which explains my mixture of `\^p` with `\hat{p}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need braces for the subscripts: `\mu_{\hat{p}}` and `\sigma_{\hat{p}}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item $\mu_{\hat{p}}$ is the mean of all possible values of $\hat{p} = \pi$.
\item $\sigma_{\hat{p}}$ represents the  standard deviation of all possible values of $\hat{p} =     \sqrt{\frac{\pi(1-\pi)}{n}}$
\item CLT (for $\hat{p}$): If $n\pi \geq 10$ \underline{AND} $n(1-\pi) \geq to$, then the histogram of all possible values of $\hat{p}$ will be approximately normal.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I also changed the text `\^p` to the math `\hat{p}` for consistency's sake, and suppressed the `\\` at the end of each `\item` (those produce undefull `\hboxes`). Perhaps instead of `$n(1-\pi) \geq to$` you meant something like `$n(1-\pi) \geq t_{0}$`?

Underlining it's not a nice typographical feature, so I would also suggest you to suppress it.

Comment: Would you also remove the underlining?

Comment: @egreg I added a recommendation to suppress it.

Comment: I think it's supposed to say `10` instead of `to`.

Comment: @Mico perhaps, but I am not sure, so I just left a comment suggesting to revisit that inequality.

Comment: Thanks Gonzalo! And yes, that was supposed to say 10. oops.